# Can I create a new remote site setting through apex code ?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I get the endpoint where the request has to be sent at runtime. Later i want to send an HTTP post request to this endpoint, so I have to create a remote site setting too at runtime.

Is there a way to create a remote site setting through apex code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do what you're asking (I couldn't find one). To allow creating Remote Site Settings using Apex would create a lot of security problems; that is probably why it's not allowed.

However, I was able to find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6832695/549141) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836769/549141) with some recommendations that relate to this question.

> "The best way I've found to save configuration values is to use Apex [Custom Settings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#kanchor672).  To set the Remote Site settings programmatically you could use the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_remotesitesetting.htm#kanchor148)." - [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75802/adam)

Comment: Mathew > Can you please elaborate the idea of programmatically setting remote sites using Metadata API ?

Comment: You would have to read the [linked document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_remotesitesetting.htm#kanchor148). I've never attempted something like that myself.

Comment: I have read in one of the developer discussion boards that we cannot use Metadata API in Apex code. Is it right?

Comment: So then what is the way to programmatically set Remote Site Setting ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no way to create/edit Remote Site Settings in Apex.